# Oil or latex for Grade 5 metal parts, in use case not requiring hard wear

Tags: painting, metal

I have a possible need to coat hardware parts in a rigging application to reduce visibility. This installation is indoors, in a semi-climate-controlled enclosed space (a church; no worries about rain, but the temperature will fluctuate between 60 and 85*F as the HVAC is told to maintain more or less strict temperature ranges for Sunday services and other functions versus "downtime" during the week). It's overhead rigging; once it's in place and painted/coated, it won't be touched for years, so I'm not worried about physical durability of the coating against abrasion. There are a couple different alloys involved, but it's pretty much all steel; the cable is galvanized 7x7 aircraft cable (yes I can buy it pre-coated but I would prefer not to), the clips and thimbles are zinc alloy stainless, and most other pieces (eyebolts, turnbuckles) are Grade 5 medium carbon steel.

So, do I go eco-friendly with a zero-VOC satin latex just to camouflage the parts, or do I still need an oil paint to ensure that the coating won't fail due to the temperature swings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an oil based primer (perhaps one advertising rust inhibition), after cleaning the parts.  The medium steel will suffer more from humidity swings than temperature swings.

Once primed, the zero VOC latex will be fine.